# How to preserve single and double quotes in a link using REGEX?

Tags: php, html, regex

I have a regex code which finds all URLs and replaces them with a HTML link. Here is my code:

```
// initializing
$str = "this is a good website www.example.com/classname/methodname/arg";

$rexProtocol = '(https?://)?';
$rexDomain   = '((?:[-a-zA-Z0-9]{1,63}\.)+[-a-zA-Z0-9]{2,63}|(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})';
$rexPort     = '(:[0-9]{1,5})?';
$rexPath     = '(/[!$-/0-9:;=@_\':;!a-zA-Z\x7f-\xff]*?)?';
$rexQuery    = '(\?[!$-/0-9:;=@_\':;!a-zA-Z\x7f-\xff]+?)?';
$rexFragment = '(#[!$-/0-9:;=@_\':;!a-zA-Z\x7f-\xff]+?)?';

function callback($match){
    // Prepend http:// if no protocol specified
    $completeUrl = $match[1] ? $match[0] : "http://{$match[0]}";
    $DetectProperName = strlen($match[2].$match[3].$match[4]) > 20 ? "...".substr($match[2].$match[3].$match[4],0,20) : $match[2].$match[3].$match[4];
    return '<a href="' . $completeUrl . '" target="_blank">'.$DetectProperName. '</a>';
}

echo $str =  preg_replace_callback("&\\b$rexProtocol$rexDomain$rexPort$rexPath$rexQuery$rexFragment(?=[?.!,;:\"]?(\s|$))&",'callback', htmlspecialchars($str));
```

Also here is the **output:**

```
this is a good website <a href="http://www.example.com/classname/methodname/arg" target="_blank">...www.example.com/clas</a>
```

Also here is a [fiddle](https://3v4l.org/b3mCI)

---

Well, that's ok and it works as well for links. Now my question is about when input is containing a quote `'` or `"`. That regex will add a `\` next to it. How can I fix it? I want such a regex be not sensitive to quotes.

Here is an example:

**Input:**

```
$str = 'this is a " (quote)';
```

**Current Output:**

```
this is a \" (quote)
```

**What I want:**

```
this is a " (quote)
```

How can I do that?

---

**Edit:** According to some tests, I figured out that change single/double quotes to ASKII code. How can I prevent it?

Comment: Find and replace single or double quotes with their respective ASCII codes.

Comment: I do not see the issue here, I ran this through IDEOne, and the output looks as expected: https://ideone.com/pyERRb

Comment: @Mike You are right and I find the problem ...! That's passing a parameter using POST-method ..! If that parameter be containing quote, it when I receive that using PHP `$_POST['arg']`, that quote will be with along a backslash behind it ..!